# "Arduino" undefined using HX711 library with Particle Photon

Tags: arduino, particle-photon

I'm trying to make an IoT scale using HX711 [technical](http://image.dfrobot.com/image/data/SEN0160/hx711_english.pdf) with a cell and a particle photon.

When flashing the code to Photon I receive an error in the library:

```
In file included from weightsensor.ino:3:0:
HX711.h:4:5: warning: "ARDUINO" is not defined [-Wundef]
 #if ARDUINO >= 100
```

Is there any other library which is not arduino specific or is there a way to fix this in an easy way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a HX711 library for Particle devices maintained by the community: [HX711ADC](https://build.particle.io/libs/HX711ADC/0.0.2/tab/HX711ADC.cpp).

You can use it in the [Web IDE](https://docs.particle.io/tutorials/developer-tools/build/xenon/#using-libraries), [CLI](https://docs.particle.io/tutorials/developer-tools/cli/#using-libraries) or the [Desktop IDE](https://docs.particle.io/tutorials/developer-tools/dev/#using-community-libraries).